# Report Processing Exception - Visual Studio 2017/2019

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, reportviewer

How do I resolve this issue?

> ReportProcessingException: The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

I tried to change the header of my RDLC to:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

But when I build it, it will change or undo my last edit and appear as below:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```